# Neo4j java driver number of threads management

Tags: java, neo4j, driver

I am using Neo4j java driver 1.7.5. I noticed that after successive calls, the number of Neo4jDriverIO threads is increasing until it achieves the max number of 2 * CPUs.

Is there a way to control the number of Neo4jDriverIO threads ? Is this max number 2 * CPUs a normal default configuration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Neo4j java driver maintainers, the max number of 2 * CPUs Neo4jDriverIO threads is the default behavior. It will be possible to control the number of threads starting with incoming 4.0.0 java driver version. See this [discussion](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/pull/652#issuecomment-560468506).